# How to allow the paste event with this jQuery Plug-in?

Tags: jquery, regex, events, jquery-plugins, paste

I'm using the following jQuery plug-in to only allow users to enter certain alpha numeric characters. Can someone please tell me how to update it so it will allow the paste event?

```
input.keypress(function (e) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);

    if (ch.indexOf(key) !== -1 && !e.ctrlKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change from the `keypress` to the `keyup` event then the user will be able to complete their paste before the code kicks in and validates.

Here is a demo of the different events: http://jsfiddle.net/FckGw/

Comment: Wish everything was this easy. THANKS!